# Allow empty itemize/enumerate/description (no \item)

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I am auto-generating a LaTeX document. The input data can possibly generate empty data, so that I am left with something like this in the generated TeX source:

```
\begin{itemize}

\end{itemize}
```

This leads to `lualatex` complaining when compiling (of course):

> Misplaced \item

Is there a way to make it ignore any empty list (no `\item`) silently?

For clarification: I do have a lot of `itemize` lists in the document and *some* can be empty depending on my data. I know I *could* filter that before generation, but that would be more cumbersome than a potential LaTeX solution.

Comment: Do you also have active itemize in your document?

Comment: I use custom envronments defined through the `enumitem` package, so the full error reads `! Package enumitem Error: Misplaced \item.` in my case, but it is a general TeX problem, right?

Answer (score 1):

I am writing yet another answer because I feel the strategy used for both of my answers is different fundamentally.

First of all, this one is a hack! You will have to replace all of your `itemize`s with `newitemize`s. As you have mentioned earlier, if you are automating the input, you can pre-define your program to generate `newitemize` and not `itemize`. If you do this then your problem is almost solved with something like following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{newitemize}{\begin{itemize} \item}{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{newitemize}

    \end{newitemize}
\end{document}
```

Similarly you can form new environments for all of your list structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other active `itemize` (or other lists) -

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewenvironment{empty}{}{}

\begin{document}
abcd
    \begin{empty} % This list structure was renamed to empty.

    \end{empty}

    \begin{itemize} % This list structure is still active.
        \item
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a neat idea but too extreme in my case with several `itemize` environments around.

Comment: Well if you have some `itemize` which you want to be active and some to be inactive, you are probably going to need some manual interference...

Comment: In that case I would have to build some logic. That is okay, I just wondered if I could make LaTex ignore it directly. Thanks for your effort though, Niranjan!

Comment: You can rename all of your empty list structures with something like `empty` and keep active structures intact. This is very simple with find and replace provided by some editors. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about you take advantage of `item[]` which creates a new item without a label.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \noindent Our first list:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item[]
    \item Fourth item
  \end{itemize}
  Our second list:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[]
  \end{itemize}
  Our third list:   
  \begin{itemize}
    \item First of all
    \item[] Second of all
    \item Thirdly
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately that does not work in my case with added logic through the `enumitem` package (`,` between items and `.` after the last one).

Comment: It would have been better for the both of us if you would have posted a minimal and complete example of what you have. Your original post used only `itemize` and had no mentioning of `enumitem`.